# How to program python to auto stop a long output

Tags: python, command-line, raspberry-pi, raspbian

So I am creating a python script that I want to make it run in a loop that outputs numbers but how do I make python stop itself?

Basically my question is how do I make python use Ctrl+C or something else and stop itself?

Comment: Have you even tried to Ctrl+C on your python program?

Answer (score 2):

If this is what you're saying, here is an example:

```
while True:
    #do your number things here
    if the_number == some_amount:
        break
```

You use the `break` command when you reach a certain condition to break out of a `while` or `for` loop.

Hopefully this is what you wanted.  If you have questions, ask away in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending the Control-C signal through os.kill().
http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

This is for sending the Control C singal to the process and not for ending a loop (Remolten's Solution).